# GNOME Terminal problem using xrdp version 0.9.5-2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: gnome-terminal, remote-desktop, xrdp

I installed xrdp version 0.9.5-2 on Ubuntu 18.04.1.
When clicking on the Gnome Terminal icon in the remote desktop login, the Gnome Terminal was started in another login of the same user on the Ubuntu server. The window manager used is xfce4.
Any ideal?